# Twitter Bootstrap display rest of a table rows using collapse.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that displays list of rows, I want to show just the first five rows and collapse the other until we click at the fifth row the we can display therest of it.

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Visits</th>
        <th>Hit</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dj7Y/888/)
Any help with this? Thanks

Comment: Found an example of this here: http://www.bootply.com/122871